# Incrementar valor de un span que está dentro de un for

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito incrementar unos valores contenidos en etiquetas span y esta es la forma en la que lo hago

Esta es la parte del javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".incrementar", function(e)
    {
        var num = $(this).attr('data-value');
        $elemento = "#" + $(this).attr('data-name');
        $($elemento).html(++num);
    });
</script>
```

Y esta la parte del html

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++): ?>
    Número <span id="number<?=$i?>" class="numeros"><?=$i?></span>
    <a href="#" class="incrementar" data-value="<?=$i?>" data-name="number<?=$i?>">Incrementar</a>
    <br>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Funciona correctamente. Se me ocurrió crear el atributo "id" en el elemento span y los atributos "data-value" y "data-name" en el elmento a href, para recoger esos datos en javascript y luego incrementar el valor en uno, pero realmente este bucle for es muy pequeño y en el caso de que el bucle sea más grande, que lo será, se tendrán que crear muchos atributos data-value y data-name para recoger esos valores

¿Se podría hacer de otra manera sin tener que crear el atributo id del span y los atributos data-value y data-name del a href?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, puedes coger el elemento previo, que seria el `span` y luego incrementar su valor

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".incrementar", function(e)
    {
        const elem = $(this).prev();
        let num = parseInt(elem.text());
        elem.html(++num);
    });
</script>

<?php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++): ?>
    Número <span class="numeros"><?=$i?></span>
    <a href="#" class="incrementar">Incrementar</a>
    <br>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Perfecto! ¿Pero por qué se usa const y let en lugar de poner var para crear las variables? Gracias!

Comment: let y const son dos formas de declarar variables en JavaScript introducidas en ES6, puedes leer mas en cualquier articulo. Te recomiendo este https://cybmeta.com/var-let-y-const-en-javascript